# Internal disk failed with bad superblock, how to fix?

Tags: fedora, hard-disk, data-recovery, ext4, superblock

**NOTE**: The operating system I'm using is on a separate disk (`/dev/sdb`).

---

I tried to mount my old root partition (`/dev/sda12`) as usual with the following command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda12 /mnt
```

However, it gave me this error:

```
mount: /dev/sda12: can't read superblock
```

So, I tried to fix it with `e2fsck -f /dev/sda12`:

```
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda12
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

That didn't work, so I tried all of the alternative superblocks I could find.

They either gave me this error:

```
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sda12

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

or this one:

```
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read        while trying to open /dev/sda12
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

Trying to view the partitions with `parted -l` or GParted both spit out numerous errors involving every single partition in `/dev/sda`.

GParted showed me like 35 errors, before it showed that the disk was completely unallocated, except the unallocated text had a caution symbol next to it.

The Disks utility showed me all the partitions, and said that it was OK, but had 16 bad sectors; /dev/sda12 was recognized as "Unknown" however.

Parted did the same thing as GParted, it couldn't show any partitions.

At this point, I am lost.

**Is there any way to recover my data, and if so how?**

---

**NOTE**: The partition was formatted as `ext4`, and contained the root partition of an Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 install. SMART tests say the disk is OK, but it has 16 bad sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, restarting the computer brought back all partitions and data.

Comment: Make sure you have everything backed up now — I wouldn't count on it staying working.

Comment: @mattdm I had already backed up my data, so I wasn't concerned about it; I was more of wanting to repair the drive, but it seems to have fixed itself.